# Batch - Loop through comma delimited string

Tags: batch-file, cmd, wmic

I'm trying to loop through fields for wmic, whose output then gets written to a text file.

The goal in the end, is to have a tab (or other) delimited file of hardware information. I can't seem to loop past the first command, the execution ends on the first execution of each loop.

Haven't worked much with batch file before, please help me get this sorted out.

```
::@ECHO OFF

:: Prompt user for computer name
SET /P id="Enter Computer Name: "

::Fetch IP
FOR /F "skip=4 usebackq tokens=2" %%a IN (`nslookup %id%`) DO (
SET ip=%%a
)

::Change working directory to .bat file location
CD %~dp0

::Creates/Clears record.
break > %id%.txt

REM Level 1: Loops through fields to be pulled
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=," %%c IN ("computersystem get name,computersystem get name,computersystem get name") DO (

    REM Level 2: Pulls value in key=value format, parses value by '=' delimiter
    FOR /F "tokens=2 delims==" %%x IN ('
        wmic %%c /value
    ') DO (
        REM Level 3: Removes line carriage, adds a <tab> character. 
        FOR /f %%z IN ("%%x") DO (
            <nul set /p = %%z
            <nul set /p = " "
        )>> %id%.txt
    )

)
```

Comment: The `FOR /F` command uses single quotes to parse the execution of a command when not using the `usebackq` option.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I had it that way before.
Still only executes the loop one time though, the first iteration of each loop.

Comment: Use `rem`, not `::` for comments within a `code block` (parenthesised series of lines)

Comment: I am not quite understanding why you are doing what you are doing with your code.  You prompt for the computer name but then you attempt to have WMIC get the computer name three times.  The computer name is also a system variable so both sets of code seems redundant.  Your code is not making any logical sense to me.  Regardless of that, I think what you are trying to do is: `FOR %%c IN ("computersystem get name","computersystem get name","computersystem get name") DO (`. You will then access the `FOR` variable like this: `wmic %%~c /value`.

Comment: Yeah those are just placeholders, which fields I'm pulling have yet to be defined. I'm focusing on building out the process by which the wmic commands are run. The ultimate purpose of this is to pull a list of fields from machines on the network using wmic /node: which is why I prompt for the computer name as a host, and nslookup the IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using a `For /F` loop at `Level 1:` instead of a standard `For` loop:

```bat
@Echo Off
CD /D "%~dp0"
Set /P "ID=Enter Computer Name: "
For /F "Tokens=2" %%A In ('NSLookUp %ID% 2^>Nul') Do Set "IP=%%A"
(For %%A In ("ComputerSystem Get Name","ComputerSystem Get Name",
 "ComputerSystem Get Name") Do For /F "Tokens=1* Delims==" %%B In (
    'WMIC %%~A /Value 2^>Nul') Do For /F "Tokens=*" %%D In ("%%~C"
) Do <Nul Set /P=%%D    )>"%ID%.txt"
```

***Note:***         The whitespace before the final closing parenthesis is a <kbd>TAB</kbd>